# Connected sets and connected supports

Tags: general-topology, analysis, measure-theory

Assume X to be connected and endowed with a probability measure $\mu$, absolutely continuous with respect to the Lebesgue measure. I have two functions defined on X that have the same gradient on the support of $\mu$. I would like to conclude that the two functions then differ by a constant due to the Intermediate Value Theorem, but this requires the support of $\mu$ to be connected: are the hypothesis I mentioned sufficient to show connectedness of the support?

Comment: What do you mean by "gradient" in this case? Does $X$ have a norm?

Comment: Is $X\subseteq \mathbb R$?  $X\subseteq \mathbb R^n$?  Regardless, no, there is no reason from the assumptions you listed to think the support needs to be connected - you could have $X=\mathbb R$ and $\mu$ supported on a fat Cantor set. (Or simply two disjoint intervals)

Comment: Yes, $X \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: If the two intervals are disjoint, can it be the case that the functions differ by two different constants, one for each interval? This is what I want to avoid.